# Validation in yup with type

Tags: node.js, forms, validation, yup

i'm trying to do a valitdation with yup in the type of a data, but i want to show a message and can't set that, with a type different of string it's showing the default message.

How can I change this message?

```
let userSchema = yup.object({
  nome: yup
    .string()
});

async function validateCreateUser(req, res, next) {

  try {
    await userSchema.validate(req.body)
      .then(() => {
        return next()
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.errors[0] })
      })
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.errors });
  }
}
```

I already tryed to use the .strict() but i can't set the message too